# Is it possible to publish a spreadsheet as an rss feed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, rss, google-sheets-api

I want to be able to read data from a Google Sheet as RSS so that I can connect it via IFTTT to other applications. Reading directly from Google Drive doesn't seem to be supported by IFTTT so I'm trying to find a workaround and RSS feeds seem to be the most robust.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHZL_enOM751OM751&q=google+spread+sheet+to+rss&oq=google+spread+sheet+to+rss&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2788966.2797049.0.2797239.36.24.0.0.0.0.548.2780.3-1j3j2.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..30.6.2776.6..0j0i10i42k1j0i10k1j35i39k1j0i20k1.GXBm5Xf-Eug

Comment: I've google'd it. I didn't find an answer on the first few pages. Let me know if you do.

Comment: I'd say yes.  Do you know how to create XML Documents is the same question? Checkout this [link](https://www.xul.fr/en-xml-rss.html#publishing-feed)